# Browser shows the CSS hamburger icon have three bars with different height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a hamburger icon menu by using only CSS. 
My implementation is below. I put that three span tags in HTML document.

```css
.sidebar-toggle {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar-toggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 0.2rem;
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar-toggle">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the browser(Chrome and IE) shows that three bars(span tags) have different height and margin like the picture below.

[image: hamburger icon]

I gave it a different height and margin value which are bigger, then it shows the right answer. So I carefully guess that the resolution of browser caused this issue.

Or is there any problem with this CSS hamburger icon implementation?

Comment: Can you also include your HTML please.

Comment: @sol Added it. But It seems to be not a problem

Comment: can you post the style of the container?

Comment: @karthick Container just has margin-left,right values. It's 1.2rem.

Comment: I used 'px' instead of 'rem', and it shows right result. However, I don't know yet what the problem is. :(

Answer (score -1):

There are better techniques to achive that, i recomend using box shadow:

```css
.box-shadow-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0.25em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 0.15em;
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 
    0 0.25em 0 0 black,
    0 0.5em 0 0 black;
}
```

```html
<div class='box-shadow-menu'></div>
```